# Python: Construct a class from subtraction/addition

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, inheritance, constructor

I'm trying to generate a child class from two parents, which is built as its sum/subtraction. I will try to explain best with a simple example.

Picture I have the following parent classes.

```
class UpperBody():
    
    def __init__(self, owner='John', age=25, max_lifting_weight=100):
        self.owner=owner # Identifier, who "owns" this upper body
        self.age=age # Second identifier
        self.max_lifting_weight=max_lifting_weight
    
    def __add__(self, other):
        #__sub__ would be equivalent
        if other.age!=self.age:
            raise AttributeError('You cannot add body parts with different ages!')
        if other.owner!=self.owner:
            print('This does not seem to fit here, but alright...')
            return UpperBody(self.owner + '_' + other.owner, self.age, self.max_lifting_weight + other.max_lifting_weight)
        
        return UpperBody(self.owner, self.age, self.max_lifting_weight + other.max_lifting_weight)
            
    def can_lift(self, weight):
        # Returns boolean
        return weight < self.max_lifting_weight


class LowerBody():
    
    def __init__(self, owner='John', age=25, max_lifting_weight=100):
        self.owner=owner # Identifier, who "owns" this lower body
        self.age=age # Second identifier
        self.max_lifting_weight=max_lifting_weight
    
    def __add__(self, other):
        #__sub__ would be equivalent
        if other.age!=self.age:
            raise AttributeError('You cannot add body parts with different ages!')
        if other.owner!=self.owner:
            print('This does not seem to fit here, but alright...')
            return UpperBody(self.owner + '_' + other.owner, self.age, self.max_lifting_weight + other.max_lifting_weight)
        
        return UpperBody(self.owner, self.age, self.max_lifting_weight + other.max_lifting_weight)
            
    def can_lift(self, weight):
        # Legs are stronger
        return weight < self.max_lifting_weight * 1.2
```

And I would like to generate the *Human* child class by **adding** the two parent classes. Something as such,

```
class Human(UpperBody, LowerBody):
    
    def __init__(self, name, age, max_lifting_weight_upper, max_lifting_weight_lower):
        self.name=name
        self.age=age
        # From here on, I have no clue how to follow. This does not load to "self", obviously.
        UpperBody.__init__(name, age, max_lifting_weight_upper) + LowerBody.__init__(name, age, max_lifting_weight_upper)
```

And later on access to methods like *can_lift* which are defined in the parent classes.

The best I could come up with would be through a function, as so,

```
def HumanConstructor(UpperBody, LowerBody):
    return UpperBody + LowerBody
```

However, if the *Human* class were to have additional methods, this would not be of much help. ¿Is there a way of doing this?

Thanks beforehand!

Comment: I would take a read on this great multiple inheritance doc - https://www.python-course.eu/python3_multiple_inheritance.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically just need to initialise the subclasses within the Human class correctly:

```py
class Human(UpperBody, LowerBody):
    
    def __init__(self, name, age, max_lifting_weight_upper, max_lifting_weight_lower):
        self.name=name
        self.age=age

        # create the child class instances
        UpperBody.__init__(name, age, max_lifting_weight_upper)
        LowerBody.__init__(name, age, max_lifting_weight_upper)

    def do_something(self):
        UpperBody.can_lift()
        LowerBody.can_lift()
```

Comment: Wow, so simple yet it went right through my head, I was already making super complicated structures. Thanks a lot!